# Play Selected MP3 Files from Array

Tags: javascript, php, html

My web page contains a PHP table with some 900 rows. There is an audio file that corresponds to each row. I would like the user to be able to check a box next to the records he/she wants to listen to, then click a single "play" button at the top of the screen to generate sequential playback of the selected files.

I've added a check box next to each record like this:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='play[]' value='$mp3'" . "</td>";
```

And at the top of the page I have my audio player:

```
      <audio controls id="audioPlayer">
  <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myverses/Mark10verse43.mp3" type="audio/ogg" onend="nextverse()'"></audio>
```

Right now, the audio player won't play at all. How can I make it play the first item in my array, then proceed to the second, and so on? I suspect this will require javascript. Here's the javascript I'm working with:

```
function nextverse() {
var i = 1;
var nextVideo = "play[0]";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
     nextVideo = play[i]; i++;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have so far

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer I have added more detail in my original post.